# JNA - Can't find Shared Object

Tags: java, centos, tesseract, jna

I'm trying to use Tesseract OCR within some Java code on Linux (CentOS 6), but I'm getting an error telling me it can't load the shared object file 'liblept.so.4' (No such file or directory).

I've run ldconfig, and I've set -Djna.library.path=/usr/local/lib/, which is where liblept.so.4 is located (I've checked, and it is there).

I'm out of ideas where to go from here, so any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: If `/usr/local/lib` is already in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (and thus in `java.library.path`), then setting `jna.library.path` is superfluous.  Make sure the path is a valid file or a valid link; it'll also fail if it's a symlink to something that doesn't exist.  When you find the actual file, JNA will also accept an absolute, full pathname.